# Computing multiple variance of a dataset in R

Tags: r, plyr

My problem is somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184065/r-calculate-variance-for-datav1-for-each-different-value-in-datav2) question.

I have a data as below

```
V1   V2
..   1
..   2
..   1
..   3
```

I need to calculate variance of data in `V1` for each value of `V2` cumulatively (This means that for a particular value of `V2` say `n`,all the rows of `V1` having corresponding `V2` less than `n` need to be included.

Will `ddply` help in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `ddply` will help since it is built on the concept of taking *non-overlapping* subsets of a data frame.

```
d <- data.frame(V1=runif(1000),V2=sample(1:10,size=1000,replace=TRUE))
u <- sort(unique(d$V2))
ans <- sapply(u,function(x) {
    with(d,var(V1[V2<=x]))
})
names(ans) <- u
```

I don't know if there's a more efficient way to do this ...

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the problem for me. I'll wait for sometime for an alternative answer, otherwise will accept your solution!

Comment: Ben's answer is simple and to the point.   Probably isn't gonna get much better.

Comment: I think you could do something where you computed the sum of `V1` and the sum of `V1^2` for each piece, computed cumulative sums, and computed the cumulative variance from that, but it would be a little bit tricky ...