# Multiple Variance of a data set in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am playing around some concept with R. This question is an extension of what I asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446789/computing-multiple-variance-of-a-dataset-in-r)

I have a data as below

```
V1   V2 V3
..   1  1
..   2  1
..   1  2
..   3  2
```

As in the earlier question, I would like to calculate variance of `V1` for each value of `V2` cumulatively. However, I need to split the dataset according to values of `V3` and calculate the variance of each individual datasets. I can do this using `split` function and then use the technique described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446789/computing-multiple-variance-of-a-dataset-in-r) answer. Is there a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: So you essentially want to do the same thing as in the earlier question, but for every unique combination of `V2` and `V3` instead of `V2` alone?

Comment: No, I want to split the data frame according to `V3` and calculate the cumulative variance for each of the resulting datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Ben Bolker's solution to your earlier question
bens.func <- function(d){
    u <- sort(unique(d$V2))
    ans <- sapply(u,function(x) {
        with(d,var(V1[V2<=x]))
    })
    names(ans) <- u
    ans
}

# Your new dataset
d <- data.frame(V1=runif(1000),V2=sample(1:10,size=1000,replace=TRUE),
                V3=sample(1:10,size=1000,replace=TRUE))

# Split and lapply takes care of the rest
lapply(split(d, d$V3), bens.func)
```

Comment: or `library(plyr); ddply(d, "V3", bens.func)`

Comment: Yes this is it. Basically, I need to get more familiar with the apply family. Thanks!

Comment: @hardikudeshi see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega